# How can I implement Metropolis Hastings algorithm in an undirected connected graph in R?

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph, markov-chains

I have posted a problem in Stack Mathematics regarding a Metropolis Hastings algorithm in graph which someone can read it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590084/metropolis-hastings-algorithm-on-markov-chain)

(A code solution is written in the stack mathematics link but it is in the CoCalc and I do not know how to translate in R.)

In a nutshell the problem is: Consider a finite, undirected, connected graph =(,)
with vertex set  and edge set . We do not know the length of || of the vertices of , nor its structure. We can only see local information about . E.g. if we are at a vertex ∈ we can see the neighbors of , i.e. the vertices ∈ for which (,)∈, as well as how many neighbors 's neighbors have. Let us denote by () the degree of ∈ the number of neighbors of .

1. Compute the transition probabilities of the chain {}∈ of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm simulating the uniform distribution in  using those of the random walk in   as the proposal transition probabilities.

For simplicity let us assume that the graph has 5 vertices.

How can I write the MH algorithm in R for this specific problem or translate the Cocalc in the stack math answer ?

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this, but you're more likely to receive help if you show some code that other people can start from. This would also show that you did some research on this question

Comment: A very gentle introduction to the Metropolis Hastings Algorithm, including R code,  can be found here: 
[The Metropolis Hastings Algorithm, Matthew Stephens, April 23, 2018] 
(https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/MH_intro.html ).

To familiarize yourself with Markov chains and its stationary distribution,
google `Math, Markov, "drunken sailor", for non technical explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**,
(i) ## CoCalc code in R (rather slow).

```
## CoCalc code in R.
library(igraph)

# g <- graph(c(1,2, 2,4, 4,1, 1,3), directed=FALSE) 
g <- graph_from_literal(A-B, B-D, D-A, A-C)

cur = 1
freq <- rep(0, vcount(g))
names(freq) <- as_ids(V(g))
nit <- 1E4

set.seed(1)
system.time({
for ( i in seq(nit) ) {
  neigh    <- V(g)[.nei(cur)]
  nextnode <- neigh[sample(length(neigh), 1)]
  if (runif(1) < degree(g, cur) / degree(g, nextnode) ){
    cur <- nextnode
  }
  freq[cur] <- freq[cur] + 1
}
}) 
freq <- freq / sum(freq)
freq
```

Output.

```
  user  system elapsed 
   4.63    0.05    5.13 

     A      B      D      C 
0.2471 0.2477 0.2463 0.2589
```

Regarding your point (ii) in [Stack Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590084/metropolis-hastings-algorithm-on-markov-chain).
If in an (un)dirceted graph all cycles are even, then the graph is bipartite and aperiodic.
As in this example. Degrees may be different.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_literal(A-X, X-B, B-Y, Y-A, A-Z)
degree(g)
mmm <- as.matrix(g[])
mmm <- mmm / rowSums(mmm)

## Calculate power serie.
mms <- mmm
mms <- mms %*% mmm; mms
```

Comment: this is the correct answer.Not the previous one.Either way it's fine.That can do.I appreciate your effort and your work.Really.Thanks a  lot.

Comment: @Homer Jay Simpson, Stackoverflow has a way to mark good answers. You will see a green check mark. Do that, then everyone immediately sees that the question has been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: no no I edited.You will now lose them

Answer (score 3):

Here is an "amlost-equivalent" translation into `R` from `CoCalc`, but with some improvements in the speed performance

```
G <- graph_from_literal(0 - -1, 0 - -3, 0 - -2, 1 - -3)
nit <- 1e4
cur <- 1
deg <- degree(G)
neighs <- setNames(ego(G, mindist = 1), V(G))
freq <- setNames(rep(0, vcount(G)), V(G))
for (k in seq(nit)) {
  nb <- neighs[[cur]]
  nxt <- nb[sample(length(nb), 1)]
  if (runif(1) < deg[cur] / deg[nxt]) {
    cur <- nxt
  }
  freq[cur] <- freq[cur] + 1
}
p <- proportions(freq)
```

where `neighs` and `deg` are prepared in advanced to avoid calling functions `neighbors` and `degree` within the loop, since they are expensive.

---

## Benchmark

You can see the benchmark below (I used `nit <- 1e2` to save time but still valid to show the performance differernce)

```
g <- graph_from_literal(0 - -1, 0 - -3, 0 - -2, 1 - -3)
nit <- 1e2

f_TIC <- function() {
  set.seed(1)
  cur <- 1
  deg <- degree(g)
  neighs <- setNames(ego(g, mindist = 1), V(g))
  freq <- setNames(rep(0, vcount(g)), V(g))
  for (k in seq(nit)) {
    nb <- neighs[[cur]]
    nxt <- nb[sample(length(nb), 1)]
    if (runif(1) < deg[cur] / deg[nxt]) {
      cur <- nxt
    }
    freq[cur] <- freq[cur] + 1
  }
  setNames(proportions(freq), names(V(g)))
}

f_clp <- function() {
  set.seed(1)
  cur <- 1
  freq <- rep(0, vcount(g))
  names(freq) <- as_ids(V(g))
  for (i in seq(nit)) {
    neigh <- V(g)[.nei(cur)]
    nextnode <- neigh[sample(length(neigh), 1)]
    if (runif(1) < degree(g, cur) / degree(g, nextnode)) {
      cur <- nextnode
    }
    freq[cur] <- freq[cur] + 1
  }
  freq / sum(freq)
}

microbenchmark(
  f_TIC(),
  f_clp(),
  check = "identical",
  times = 20L
)
```

and you will see

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 f_TIC() 14.6516 14.96495 17.54595 15.59415 19.63485  27.0141    20
 f_clp() 54.8336 59.41840 63.09275 60.19275 64.41965 103.8254    20
```

Comment: awesome answer.Thank you very much for your effort and time in this question.I really appreciate it.

Comment: Very nice improvement indeed. Didn't know about `ego()`, `proportions()` and forgot `setNames()`. (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Sources

- The Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, Christian P. Robert, https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.01896
- The Metropolis Hastings Algorithm, Matthew Stephens, https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/MH_intro.html

As an example, we roll two dice and use the sum as the target distribution: the sum of two dices (6 faces each).
Possible states: 2 through 12.

```
library(igraph)
freq_d2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1)
dist_d2 <- freq_d2 / 36
target  <- function(x) return(freq_d2[x-1])
```

Coding from Matthew Stephens.
Create "random walk proposal" distribution.

```
x    = rep(0, 11 * 1000)
x[1] = 3                    #initialize; I've set arbitrarily set this to 3
for ( i in tail(seq_along(x), -1) ) {
  current_x      = x[i-1]
  proposed_x     = sample(6, 1) + sample(6, 1)
  A              = target(proposed_x)/target(current_x)
  hastings_ratio = target(current_x) / target(proposed_x)
  A              = min(1, hastings_ratio * A)
  if(runif(1) < A){
    x[i] = proposed_x       # accept move with probabily min(1,A)
  } else {
    x[i] = current_x        # otherwise "reject" move, and stay where we are
  }
}

frq         <-  as.data.frame(table(x))
frq$density <- frq[,2] / sum(frq$Freq)
frq$target  <- dist_d2
frq$corr    <- cor(frq$density, frq$dist)
print(frq, digits=3)
```

Output

```
    x Freq density target  corr
1   2  305  0.0277 0.0278 0.998
2   3  611  0.0555 0.0556 0.998
3   4  953  0.0866 0.0833 0.998
4   5 1191  0.1083 0.1111 0.998
5   6 1496  0.1360 0.1389 0.998
6   7 1856  0.1687 0.1667 0.998
7   8 1568  0.1425 0.1389 0.998
8   9 1191  0.1083 0.1111 0.998
9  10  952  0.0865 0.0833 0.998
10 11  568  0.0516 0.0556 0.998
11 12  309  0.0281 0.0278 0.998
```

```
## Create a stochastic transition matrix, sample <--> next sample
## See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix
el <- cbind(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1))
g  <- graph_from_edgelist(el, directed = FALSE) - 1
pb <- as.matrix(g[]);
pb <- pb / ifelse(rowSums(pb) > 0, rowSums(pb), 1)
```

Next we demonstrate that the stationary state of the Markov chain converges to the target distribution.
The stochastic matrix pb[i,j] describes the transition probabilities from state [i] to [j]
For state s0, s1 = pb.s0 is the next state of the Markov system.
Calculate the stationary distribution of the Markov chain by
constructing the power sequence of pb, until stable.
pb<sup>1</sup>, pb<sup>2</sup>, ... describes the transition probabilities after one, two, ... transitions. pb* = pb<sup>n</sup> is stationary when pb<sup>n</sup> == pb<sup>(n+1)</sup> and pb > 0 for all elements of pb.That is, all states are reachable with positive probability.

Google, math Markov "drunken sailor", for non-technical introductions to Markov chains.

```
pb_star <- pb
for (i in seq(100)) {
  pb_next <- pb_star %*% pb
  pb_next <- pb_next
  if ( sd(pb_star - pb_next) < 1E-5) break
  pb_star <- pb_next;
}
state_d2 <- pb_star[1,]
print(cbind(state=state_d2, target=dist_d2, sd = sd(state_d2 - dist_d2)), digits=3)
```

Output.

```
     state   target      sd
 [1,] 0.0291 0.0278 0.00351
 [2,] 0.0552 0.0556 0.00351
 [3,] 0.0870 0.0833 0.00351
 [4,] 0.1119 0.1111 0.00351
 [5,] 0.1353 0.1389 0.00351
 [6,] 0.1585 0.1667 0.00351
 [7,] 0.1427 0.1389 0.00351
 [8,] 0.1146 0.1111 0.00351
 [9,] 0.0836 0.0833 0.00351
[10,] 0.0549 0.0556 0.00351
[11,] 0.0273 0.0278 0.00351
```

Comment: How many vertices has this simulated undirected  graph that you used?I hoped for an analog solution to the Stack Mathematics solution but in R.I am familiar on how the MH algorithm works.My question is regarding the graph theory how the MH algorithm might help.Anyway thanks for the try.

Comment: The graph `g' has `vcount(g) = 11` vertices and `ecount(g) = 11 * 1000 -1` edges. In this approach, the random path is created first and then the graph. As you can see, all the probabilities in `pb` are strictly positive. Therefore, the Markov chain is ergodic. You could also try `components(g)` to check the number of components (1).
Another approach is to create a random graph first and then derive the matrix (?).

Comment: @if it possible to translate the 4 vertices graph as posted in the solution on stack mathematics in R

Comment: I converted the CoCalc code to R, and added it. Hope this helps.

Comment: nice translation into `R` and use of `.nei()`, +1! I think you can further improve the efficiency if you don't call the `igraph` function in each iteration; Otherwise, it reads the info of the entire graph, which slows down the speed.